# Can you help me identify a flaw in my DC motor brake design

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, h-bridge

Can you please look at the schematic below and tell me what I am doing wrong.

The p-channel MOSFET always shorting no matter what I do also checked with different components and got the same result.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: changed to links

Comment: What's the Vgs on the P-MOSFET? Are you overcomming the gate threshold on your N-stage inverter in the first place?

Comment: It's pretty obvious, you have the source and drain terminals of FET1 and FET4 mixed up. Hint: the arrow points in direction of the body diode.

Comment: What Janka said. Swap pins 2 and 3.

Comment: thank you that fixed the issue and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please look at the schematic below and tell me what I am doing
>   wrong

The IRF5305 (P ch MOSFET) is upside down and the body diode will always conduct.

As for anything else, if you could take some time to explain why you might want to actively short out the motor with the P ch MOSFET, this might help.

Comment: i am trying to make the motor stop instantly using an mcu signal

Comment: @rotembuhbut That P-channel shorting-switch helps decelerate the motor, but you may be disappointed - it won't stop "instantly". The back-emf that provides braking force is most effective for a fast-turning motor, but the braking force decreases as the motor turns slower.